# Make JOptionPane readable by screen reader

Tags: java, swing, screen-readers

I have the following code in a Java application:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi", "Window", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I've used Window's reader, NVDA and JAWS, but none of read the "Hi" message inside the dialog. I've also tried using a JTextArea inside a JPanel, but they only read the window's name instead of the content itself.

Is there a way of making it readable?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the accessible JOptionPane: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.AccessibleJOptionPane.html